# JFrame and JPanel problems with calling between

Tags: jframe, jpanel

```
package pozivanjeProzora;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
SidePanel panel ;
MainWindow instanca;

public MainPanel()
{
    super();

    JButton button = new JButton("Pozdrav iz main panela");
    add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            instanca.add(panel);

        }
    });
}
}
```

So, I `extend` JFrame in my MainWindow and I created instance of it. I am in `MainPanel` class which is called in MainWindow right now. But if I come in `MainPanel` and if I click on this button I want to my MainWindow(which extends JFrame) to add panel from SidePanel class(which has one button and extends JPanel also).

But if I click on button it shows me only `NullPointerException`. Where is my foult? `MainWindow` only has couple of lines about location of window and visible and I added MainPanel there as a first panel when I run my program. But, when I call another panel from `MainPanel` and when I try to add that panel with instance of `MainWindow` it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `instanca` is never initialised. Perhaps pass it in the constructor.

i.e.

```
public MainPanel(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
  instanca = mainWindow;
```